# Transform object into array in reactJS

Tags: javascript

I have following object:

```
    {
      DepositAmt_0: 133
      DepositAmt_1: 455
      DepositAmt_2: 123
      DepositNotes_0: "some notes "
      DepositNotes_1: "some comment"
      DepositNotes_2: "some comment"
      PayReference_0: "aaa"
      PayReference_1: "bbb"
      PayReference_2: "qwerty"
      PaymentType_0: "payment"
      PaymentType_1: "card"
      PaymentType_2: "card"
}
```

This object I am getting when submitting form.

How can I transfer that object into this:

```
    [
    0:{DepositAmt:123, DepositNotes:"some notes", PayReference : "aaa", PaymentType:"payment"},
    1:{DepositAmt:455, DepositNotes:"some comment", PayReference : "bbb", PaymentType:"card"},
    2:{DepositAmt:123, DepositNotes:"some comment", PayReference : "qwerty", PaymentType:"card"},
    ]
```

Comment: What have your tried so far? Another important point would be to describe if you'll have an arbitrary amount of `DepositAmt_n` in your object or if its limited to three as illustrated in your example. Have a look at regex..

Comment: it's about the `n` number cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on list of object keys:

```js
// your initial object
const input = {
      DepositAmt_0: 133,
      DepositAmt_1: 455,
      DepositAmt_2: 123,
      DepositNotes_0: "some notes ",
      DepositNotes_1: "some comment",
      DepositNotes_2: "some comment",
      PayReference_0: "aaa",
      PayReference_1: "bbb",
      PayReference_2: "qwerty",
      PaymentType_0: "payment",
      PaymentType_1: "card",
      PaymentType_2: "card",
}

// reduce thru 'input' keys
const result = Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, el) => {
  // split each key to name and it's index
  const [name, index] = el.split('_');

  // add key to element with obtained index
  if (!acc[index]) acc[index] = {};
  acc[index][name] = input[el];
  return acc;
}, {});

// result is an object where keys are indexes 
// and values are elements you want,
// so now you get desired result using Object.values
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: Tanks @Xeelley, your solution is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```js
const data = {
  DepositAmt_0: 133,
  DepositAmt_1: 455,
  DepositAmt_2: 123,
  DepositNotes_0: "some notes ",
  DepositNotes_1: "some comment",
  DepositNotes_2: "some comment",
  PayReference_0: "aaa",
  PayReference_1: "bbb",
  PayReference_2: "qwerty",
  PaymentType_0: "payment",
  PaymentType_1: "card",
  PaymentType_2: "card",
}

const {
  keys,
  max
} = Object.keys(data).reduce((res, label) => {
  const [key, i] = label.split('_')
  return {
    keys: [...new Set([...res.keys, key])],
    max: Math.max(res.max, i)
  }
}, {
  keys: [],
  max: 0
})
const result = Array(max + 1).fill(0).map((_, i) =>{
  return keys.reduce((res, key) => {
    return {
      ...res,
      [key]: data[key + '_' + i]
    }
  }, {})
  }
)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reduce:

```js
const obj = {
  DepositAmt_0: 133,
  DepositAmt_1: 455,
  DepositAmt_2: 123,
  DepositNotes_0: "some notes ",
  DepositNotes_1: "some comment",
  DepositNotes_2: "some comment",
  PayReference_0: "aaa",
  PayReference_1: "bbb",
  PayReference_2: "qwerty",
  PaymentType_0: "payment",
  PaymentType_1: "card",
  PaymentType_2: "card"
};

const transformObject = (object) => {
  const objKeys = Object.keys(object);
  const result = objKeys.reduce((resultObject, currentProperty) => {
    const propertyNumber = currentProperty.slice(-1);
    const newPropertyKey = currentProperty.substring(0, currentProperty.length - 2);

    return {
      ...resultObject,
      [propertyNumber]: {
        ...resultObject[propertyNumber],
        [newPropertyKey]: object[currentProperty]
      },
    };
  }, {});

  return result;
};

console.log(transformObject(obj));

// 0: { DepositAmt: 123, DepositNotes: "some notes", PayReference: "aaa", PaymentType:"payment" },
// 1: { DepositAmt: 455, DepositNotes: "some comment", PayReference: "bbb", PaymentType:"card" },
// 2: { DepositAmt: 123, DepositNotes: "some comment", PayReference: "qwerty", PaymentType:"card" },
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I whipped out to do this for you:

```js
const input = {
  DepositAmt_0: 133,
  DepositAmt_1: 455,
  DepositAmt_2: 123,
  DepositNotes_0: "some notes ",
  DepositNotes_1: "some comment",
  DepositNotes_2: "some comment",
  PayReference_0: "aaa",
  PayReference_1: "bbb",
  PayReference_2: "qwerty",
  PaymentType_0: "payment",
  PaymentType_1: "card",
  PaymentType_2: "card",
};

const convertObjToArrOfObj = (obj) => {
  const convertedArr = [];

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    const newKey = key.split("_");
    const arrIndex = parseInt(newKey[1]);
    if (convertedArr[arrIndex] === undefined) {
      convertedArr.splice(arrIndex, 0, {});
    }
    let object = convertedArr[arrIndex];
    object = { ...object, [key]: value };
    convertedArr[arrIndex] = object;
  }

  return convertedArr;
};

console.log(convertObjToArrOfObj(input));
```